# Alto dinamico al generar PDF con MPDF

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

Necesito imprimir una tirilla tiquet, para un punto de venta POS, y se cuanto es el ancho, pero el alto puede variar por que depende de la cantidad de articulos, alguno sabe como puedo hacer para que al generar el PDF con MPDF el alto del pdf se ajuste al contenido y no que tenga una medida estatica pues generaria salto de pagina si el contenido se pasa del alto y seria otra pagina cuando es una sola.
muchas gracias.

Comment: La única forma que he visto para hacerlo es haciendo 2 PDFs. **El primero es el que vas a usar para obtener el alto que debería tener el segundo**. El segundo es el que finalmente "imprimes". PD: Si, es feo.